# NetBeans:JPA:Error:could not determine nor create a location for the configuration files

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, persistence, google-cloud-messaging

I'm adding JPA diagram from database in NetBeans. After I click "finish" this error message will pop up:

> Could not determine nor create a location for the configuration files.

And it's happened in a gcm demo project I download, however, using a new project will be ok. I cannot find out the different between them.

Anyone experienced a similar situation or know the meaning of this message?

Comment: Can you please post the minimum code required to reproduce the error?  We can't see what is wrong without your code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which part I should post, and I think it's not related to the code since I have already move all codes to a new project and it's works. I guess it's about project configuration, and I compared the two project properties it's turn out they are the same. Then I really don't know what to post.@hosch250

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in NetBeans 8.0.1 and the latest JPA Diagram plug in. Please post versions you are using.